# Why is memcpy() a way to add elements to a `std::map`?

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary, std, stdmap

I've been trying to make a container for shared access between threads. And I think what I'm looking for looks something like this:

```
 std::map<int, std::array<char, 256>>msg_buffers; //make atomic
```

A map of (atomic) `array<char,256>` that threads will use to relay information. The thing is though, I found I can just memcopy values into the arrays referenced by the map, and they will appear as if I added the elements normally. I have a feeling this will lead to problems later on however, and I'm curious why it doesn't cause an error, or why it works at all.

This is what it looks like:

```
#include <array>
#include <map>

std::map<int, std::array<char, 256>>charmap; //a msg queue

char charbuf[256]; //incoming msg buffer
for (int x = 0; x < 256; x++)charbuf[x] = '0'; //make arbitrary msg

//memcopy arbitrary msg **directly** to array at (non existing) map[4]
memcpy(charmap[4].data(), charbuf, sizeof(char) * 256);

//which will then magically exist
std::cout << "Used slots in charmap are: ";
if (!charmap.empty()) 
    for (auto x : charmap)std::cout << x.first << " | "; //cout existing elements
```

And elements added with `memcpy()` will appear as normal, even if I did not create the element specifically. Is this something the compiler does without me knowing? I cant see how this is a way to add elements to a map, and I feel it should be giving a warning of some kind.

I used Visual Studio 2017 to compile this.

Comment: [`T& operator[]( const Key& key ); - Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key, performing an insertion if such key does not already exist.`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at)

Comment: @tkausl that is the answer, thank you

Comment: putting in other terms, `memcopy` is not part of the picture here: it's just that calling `charmap[4]` forces (if neded) the creation of the corresponding value. 
Then you can work on the value as you need.

Comment: @GianPaolo: Moreover, if `memcpy` were *creating* anything, calling `data()` on `charmap[4]` wouldn’t work.

Answer (score 2):

`charmap[4]` returns a reference to the value with the key `4` (it automatically creates the element if it does not exist yet).  This value is of type `std::array<char, 256>`, and can be manipulated normally.  The memcpy just copies the content into this buffer, and there is no magic with memcpy here.  In particular, it does not create new elements.

Comment: Your answer is missing something crucial concerning operator[]. If the key-value pair for key '4' does not exist then operator[] _creates_ a new map entry. Thus whether the key did or did not exist before the call to operator[] it will _always_  return a valid value reference. Therefore `memcpy` works without triggering a memory exception (segfault/access violation).

Comment: @Nathilion clarified